# How to use utf8 in java MYSQL, to search special characters like à, ç, é

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate

Can some one suggest how to use utf8 in java MYSQL(Hibernate) to search special characters like "à,ç".

I have tried like this:

```
StringBuilder lSql = new StringBuilder("select count(s.id) from SampleTable s where s.deleted = false");
        if (lSearchterm != null) {
            lSql.append(" and ((UPPER(s.name) like :lSearchterm))");
        }
        Query lQuery = em.createQuery(lSql.toString());
        if (lSearchterm != null) {
            lQuery.setParameter("lSearchterm", '%' + lSearchterm.toUpperCase() + "COLLATE utf8_bin" + '%');
        }
```

Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: To avoid the obvious, have you instructed the JDBC driver to use UTF-8?

Comment: Show us how you create connector

Comment: @BalusC yes check my code i tried using COLLATE utf8_bin, but not sure its correct way or not. it works in work bench but not in the java code as mentioned above.

Comment: I didn't ask that. MySQL JDBC driver uses by default the client platform encoding to decode the SQL before transferring it over network to the MySQL DB. You need to explicitly tell the JDBC driver to use UTF-8. As you apparently have no idea what I was asking, I'll assume that you indeed didn't do that.

Comment: That COLLATE only fits at the end of the `like` string - with a space in front; not in the parameter value. Never used it like that. Also `LIKE` by default is case insensitive. Doing an SQL UPPER and java toUpperCase is a bit asking for compatibility issues in the dark corners.

Comment: Should it not be `from SampleTable s` (`s` forgotten)?

Comment: @Joop Eggen you are right I have edited my post and i am using Hibernate not JDBC, please suggest some solution!

Comment: What do you think that Hibernate/JPA is using under the covers? Didn't you realize that by the fact that you still need to supply a JDBC driver and a JDBC URL in Hibernate/JPA connection configuration?